# Underline specific line in QTextEdit C++

Tags: c++, qt

How can I underline/change color of multiple different lines of a QTextEdit? None of the previous answers found here were helpful.They all changed the color of all the QTextEdit lines

Answer (score 0):

You can use **setHtml()** method (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#html-prop) to achieve such look and feel.

Comment: I want the text just to change color or to be underlined, not to change to html look

Comment: In any case you have to use some kind of a markup language to specify that exactly this word or this line should be yellow/red/blue or underlined/bold/italic and so on. 

So, an HTML format gives you that possibility. If this doesn't work for your case, then try to use a different GUI control or create your own

Answer (score 0):

For a specific QLineEdit you can use `QWidget::setStyle(QStyle *style)`

To change text inside your QLineEdit just use style.

look at this: https://docs.huihoo.com/qt/5.x/stylesheet-examples.html

and this: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html

For example:

```
QLineEdit 
{
     border: 2px solid gray;
     border-radius: 10px;
     padding: 0 8px;
     background: yellow;
     border-bottom: 2px solid maroon;
     selection-background-color: darkgray;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example that shows you how to work with text elements in Qt:

```
    ui->textEdit->setText("this is a <a style='color:red;'>red</a> word!");
    ui->textEdit->append("This is an <u>underlined</u> text.");
    ui->textEdit->append("This is a <a style='color:red;'><u>red underlined</u></a>text.");
```

output seems as follows:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAJQW.png)